# How to reuse the submodule in Gradle?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I have two following Android Studio project, structure like this:

```
projectA/
    ├----build.gradle
    ├----settings.gradle
    ├----bluewhale/
    ├----krill/
```

projectA settings.gradle file:`include 'bluewhale', 'krill'`

```
projectB/
    ├----build.gradle
    ├----settings.gradle
    ├----hello/
    ├----krill/
```

projectB settings.gradle file:`include 'hello', 'krill'`

You can see "projectA" and "projectB" contain the same module "krill". Actually, it's a library project.

**My question is:** how to reuse the submodule "krill" in Gradle?  I don't want to include the same copy of "krill" in every project

Looking forward to your reply! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a sub-module that is used in multiple projects, you should think about extracting it to a separate project. Then you can create a dependency out of it and include it in both projects in `dependencies` section.

If you only use your local machine for development, without any custom repository, the best way would probably be to use the `mavenLocal()` repository. You can use the [maven publish plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/publishing_maven.html) to publish your jar into the local maven repository. It should be as simple as adding this to the new **krill**:

```
apply plugin: 'maven'
apply plugin: 'maven-publish'

publishing {
    publications {
        maven(MavenPublication) {
            from components.java
            artifact sourceJar {
                classifier "sources"
            }
        }
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenLocal()
}
```

You might want to set the group and artifact ID. See [the documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/publishing_maven.html) for more info.

You can also keep **krill** in one of the projects, let's say ProjectA, if it has some relation to it. Then you set up the maven publishing in the **krill** sub-module. You can also publish to maven local by running `gradle :krill:publishToMavenLocal` and then use it as dependency in ProjectB.

Another option is to save the submodule outside the projectA and projectB trees and add it using something like this:

```
include("krill")
  project(":krill") {
    projectDir = new File("$settingsDir/../krill")
}
```

But I can't recommend this because it's hacky and your IDE might have a problem with it too.

Last thing that might be possible is to create symlinks from a directory where your **krill** project is located to both ProjectA and ProjectB. But that is a really bad idea e.g. when you are using a version control.

Comment: But what if my module is frequent modify, I need to publish the (jar/aar) to the (local/remote) maven repository frequently. It's there any way to reference the module directly?

Comment: I think you can, see the update. But it's hacky. Why don't you like the publishing frequently? You should be running your unit tests anyway and publishing to local repo takes almost no time.

Comment: Thanks, I prefer to use the second way!

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found an article here: [an-alternative-multiproject-setup-for-android-studio](http://www.philosophicalhacker.com/2014/10/02/an-alternative-multiproject-setup-for-android-studio/). It works for me perfectly!

It shows us another Way different from Google’s [Gradle Plugin user guide recommends](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide)

**Sample code below:** (Add this script to your project `settings.gradle` file)

```
include ':krill'
project(':krill').projectDir = new File('../otherProject/krill')
```

**Project structure below:**

```
RootFolder/
    ├----projectA/
    │   ├----build.gradle
    │   ├----settings.gradle
    │   └----bluewhale/
    │
    ├----projectB/
    │   ├----build.gradle
    │   ├----settings.gradle
    │   └----hello/
    │
    └----otherProject/
        ├----krill/
        │   └----build.gradle
        │
        └----otherModule/
            └----build.gradle
```

For more details, visit gradle official document: [Multi Project Builds](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_lifecycle.html#sec:multi_project_builds)